# How to pass a C++ short* to managed C# assembly in C++/CLI

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I'm  having trouble passing an argument from C++/CLI code into a .NET C# function.

In C++ I have something resembling the following:

```
void SomeFunction(short *id)
{
   CSharpClass::StaticClassInstance->SetValue(id);
}
```

On the C# side, the function is declared with a ref argument as:

```
public void SetValue(ref short id)
{
  id = this.internalIdField;
}
```

The compiler error I'm getting when calling SetValue(id) is "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'short *' to 'short %'".

I found out that a tracking reference (%) is equivalent to C# ref but I don't know how to use it with the short* parameter I'm trying to pass.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The logical C++/CLI signature of `CSharpClass::SetValue` is

```
void SetValue(short% id);
```

If you know C++ (as opposed to C++/CLI), the answer here is the exact same as it would be if you had the C++ signature

```
void SetValue(short& id);
```

I.e., simply dereference the pointer:

```
void SomeFunction(short *id)
{
    CSharpClass::StaticClassInstance->SetValue(*id);
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. I could have sworn I'd already tried this but apparently I must not have because as soon as I dereferenced the pointer, it compiled. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be long winded, [declare a tracking reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/8903062a.aspx), assign the tracking reference to your id parameter and then pass the tracking reference to your function...

```
short %s = *id;

SetValue (s);
```

If you'd rather not be long winded, just dereference the pointer.  While the compiler cannot convert a short * into a short % it *can* convert a short into a short %...

```
SetValue (*id);
```