# Passing pointer from managed C++/CLI to ActiveX C++ component

Tags: visual-c++, com, c++-cli, activex, marshalling

I have an ActiveX component built in C++. One of its methods has this signature:

```
short Component::Method(short FAR* ptr) {}
```

When the I add the ActiveX into my C++/CLI application
the method signature shows as:

```
short Compnenet::Method(short% ptr) {}
```

I want to be able to correctly pass short* pSomething; variable value to this method.
of course, the new signature doesn't accept passing arguments as short*
and even if you try to cast to short% it doesn't give right results.

Note: I don't have access to the activeX control to change. I can only confirm the value of address that that the activeX method received. The method prints the passed value as follows:

```
short Component::Method(short FAR* ptr) {
    char buffer[128];
    sprintf_s(buffer, "address of ptr = %p\n", ptr);
    OutputDebugString(buffer);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass a C++ short* to managed C# assembly in C++/CLI](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6118263/636019)

Comment: I've tried to pass the pSomething to the method like Component::Method(*pSomething); it did compile but the debug message shows a different address :(

Comment: @X5X : I have no idea what you mean by that. Ignore the debugger for the moment -- does the program behave correctly at runtime?

Comment: I meant the address printed by OutputDebugString..

Comment: Anyway it didn't work most of the time it will break giving this output: First-chance exception at 0x7855ab9e in App.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x04f53000.
HEAP[App.exe]: Invalid Address specified to RtlFreeHeap( 00150000, 04F40318 )
Windows has triggered a breakpoint in App.exe.

This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in App.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.

This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while App.exe has focus.

The output window may have more diagnostic information.

Comment: @X5X : You'll need to show code that reproduces the problem, because the problem _as you've described it_ should be solved by simply dereferencing the pointer. (I suspect the **real** problem lies in how you allocated that pointer...)

Comment: I may try to re-produce the problem and upload it later. but the i've allocated the pointer in C++/CLI using new operator, and the Component::Method() simply copies the array pointed to by the parameter to a local array allocated within the ActiveX control using a memcpy statement

Comment: @X5X : If the pointer is mean to point to an array rather than a singular value, then the managed signature should be `short Compnenet::Method(array<short>^);`, not `short Compnenet::Method(short%);`.

Comment: @ildjarn: The original c++ activeX method signature is <i>short Component::Method(short FAR* ptr);</i> ptr should point to an array of shorts. However, when importing the activeX into VS2008 it shows the method as short Compnenet::Method(short% ptr). I have no control over how VS should declares this method.

Comment: @X5X : You have _complete_ control over how VS defines the method, just indirectly. You can use [Tlbimp.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt0cf3sx.aspx) to create the wrapper assembly, then use [Ildasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) to disassemble the resulting assembly, correct the signature in the generated IL text files, and use [Ilasm.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx) to recreate the wrapper assembly with the corrected signature. (cont'd)

Comment: @X5X : (cont'd) Because the type-library importer fails to get COM interface wrappers correct so often, this is a very common process, and you should be able to find many blog articles outlining the process (usually in regards to Shdocvw.dll).

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks for help. I've done the first two steps i.e tlbimp.exe and ildasm.exe and tried to modify the method signature from "instance int16  Method(int16& ptr)" to "instance int16  Method(array<int16>& ptr)" However, when i did the last step ilasm.exe it gave me a syntax error at token 'array'! at the line that I touched.

Comment: @X5X : The IL syntax for the old `short%` method should be something like `.method public hidebysig instance int16 Method(int16& ptr) cil managed`; the IL syntax for the new `array<short>^`method should be something like `.method public hidebysig instance int16 Method(int16[] ptr) cil managed`. Of course, the method implementation will need to change as well as just the signature...

Comment: @ildjarn: I've altered the method prototype in the IL form Comp::Method(short%) to Comp::Method(int16[]) and successfully linked it to VS. now the method signature appears in VS as 'short Comp::Method(cli::array<short, 1> ^ptr). i'm not sure if this will work. however, how will I pass a short* array; to this function without having to copy its content to a managed array buffer each time. aren't there are a simple way (cont'd)

Comment: isn't there a method to make the method declaration in IL accepts a native pointer directly using some directive like unsafe or something. so I can pass a native allocated array to the component who just need a correct pointer to an array to copy its data :( .. thanks.

Comment: @X5X : `short*` is not an array, it is a pointer to a `short` that may be semantically treated as a C-array in C++. There's no builtin support for marshaling this, so you'll have to do it manually: `array<short>^ arr = gcnew array<short>(nativeArrayLen); for (int i = 0; i != arr->Length; ++i) arr[i] = nativeArr[i];` where `nativeArr` is a `short*` and `nativeArrayLen` contains the number of elements in `nativeArr`.

Comment: @X5X : Yes, the signature could be modified to take a `short*` directly, but there's no built-in marshaling functionality that knows how to marshal a `short*` to an `array<short>^` -- how could there be, when it's not directly possible to know how many elements are in the `short*` C-array?

Comment: @ildjarn: the thing is if I was using this component from C++. then all i need to do is to pass ptr as comp::Method(ptr) I don't need to tell the component the size of array that ptr points to. I know the exact size of the array required by the component. I just need to pass the native pointer correctly to the ActiveX component.

Comment: so how to change the IL declaration to accept native pointer directly?

Comment: @ildjarn: I did as you mentioned. To summarize I've changed the method signature from `instance int16  Method(int16& ptr) cil managed` to `instance int16  Method(int16[] ptr) cil managed` and from the code I've allocated an `array<short>^ shortArray = gcnew array<short>(100);` and then passed it to the method `comp->Method(shortArray);` the code compiles successfully. but now I'm getting a runtime exception DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH when the method is called?!!

Comment: @X5X : As Hans' answer indicates, the unmanaged signature doesn't make much sense to begin with, so I'm not sure anyone can help you on this... Do you happen to have the IDL definition for the interface? If so, please post it, as that may be the only remaining piece to this puzzle.

Comment: @ildjarn: I've recreated the problem. here is an similar component with the same idl http://www.mediafire.com/?7px88zr16ea1rhe. The IDL is found in a file SomeComp.odl and the project generates an ActiveX with the name SomeComp.ocx. The method is named CopyToBuffer(short* ptr). (cont'd)

Comment: To recreate the problem create a C++/CLI project and add the ActiveX on some window. and then try to call the method (Maybe i've should have done this myself

Comment: I've add a test project to the solution http://www.mediafire.com/?8j1b48avrmgsisw. Thanks

Comment: @X5X : Okay; I don't have time tonight, but I'll try to look at it tomorrow if Hans doesn't beat me to it.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks for help. I've opened a new post to the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217293/passing-an-array-from-managed-code-to-unmanaged-c-activex-component trying to better explain my problem and made a slight change to the vs-solution.

Answer (score 2):

The function signature is not valid for ActiveX automation, arrays must be passed as a SAFEARRAY.  As is, the function cannot be called by any code other than native C/C++.  The type library converter has the same problem, the function signature is identical to one where the argument is passed by reference.  It has no way to guess that it is actually an array.  Which is why you got the short% type.

If you can't change the native component then you will have to edit the interop library that's generated by Tlbimp.exe.  That requires running ildasm.exe to decompile the DLL to IL.  Edit the IL declaration of the function.  Put humpty-dumpty back together with ilasm.exe.  Look at the disassembly of a little test function that has the signature you need to know how to edit the IL.  You'll need to pass the argument as an IntPtr and pass the pinned array.  Use pin_ptr<> to get that pointer.

Comment: Thanks Hans, I did most of the parts you mentioned. But I just need to mention that in C++/CLI I allocated my array as a native C++ array using 'new' keyword. so I have the array as mere short* array; and I want to pass it to the ActiveX component. I've read about pin_ptr usage and it seems to be used when you want to use a managed array as a native array (am I wrong?).

Comment: like I asked ildjarn. can't I change the IL code to let me pass a native pointer (that represents an array) directly to the activeX method. I don't know maybe if there is a magic 'unsafe' keyword in the IL!

Comment: You don't get a native pointer for free, you have to create one.  It requires you telling the garbage collector that you are breaking the rules and that it shouldn't move the object when compacting the heap.  There's no magic, you have to use pin_ptr<>.  Or GCHandle::Alloc().

Comment: Here is a project of the problem http://www.mediafire.com/?8j1b48avrmgsisw what is the correct way to do the call? Thanks

Comment: I've opened a new post to the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6217293/passing-an-array-from-managed-code-to-unmanaged-c-activex-component trying to better explain my problem and made a slight change to the supplied vs-solution.