# Passing an array from managed code to unmanaged C++ ActiveX component

Tags: c#, visual-c++, c++-cli, interop, activex

In an earlier post [Passing pointer from managed C++/CLI to ActiveX C++ component](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6144091) I've asked about the correct means to pass an array (whether managed or unmanaged array) to an activeX component created in native C++.
The activeX method has the following signature:

```
short Component::CopyToBuffer(short FAR* ptr) {}
```

when the activeX is imported to be used in C++/CLI

the method signature is displayed as

```
short Component::CopyToBuffer(short% ptr) {}
```

when imported in C# it is displayed as

```
short Component::CopyToBuffer(ref short ptr) {}
```

However, I was not able to pass the array correctly.

whether native array: `short* shortsArray = new short[500];`

neither a managed array: `array<short>^ shortsArray = gcnew array<short>(500);`

users ildjarn and Hans Passant suggested that I need to edit the interop assembly file to change the exported method signature to something like Component::(int16[] ptr) which I did and successfully compiled the project but ran into other kind of problems (type mismatch or something).

So now I've made a sample project that reproduces the problemnSolution
The solution contains:

- A project for the ActiveX component with one method CopyToBuffer found in SomeCompCtl.h
- A test project in C++/CLI. with a single form that has the activeX added to it and a button calls the method with an array of given values.
- Another test project in C# that does the same thing

To run the project:
- Simply compile SomeComp to generate Somecomp.ocx which contains the ActiveX.
- regsrv32 the ActiveX control

Please note that I don't access to the ActiveX code (I've had access to one version of code but I cannot presume that the developers will continue to provide me with updated versions of code) so any solutions shouldn't depend on changing the ActiveX interfaces or code. I normally only have the ocx file with its tlb file.

Comment: I really hope you spelled it `Component` and not `Compnenet` in the real code. :)

Comment: @Billy : I fixed a slew of 'resluts' -> 'results' typos at work last week. Good times.

Answer (score 0):

With the signature as `CopyToBuffer(short% ptr)`, how did you call it? If you did `CopyToBuffer(myArray[0])` or `CopyToBuffer(&myArray[0])`, that could fail because the garbage collector could move the array on you. Try this:

```
pin_ptr<short> pinned = &myArray[0];
component->CopyToBuffer(pinned);
```

If that doesn't work, try editing the interop assembly file again, change the signature to `CopyToBuffer(IntPtr ptr)`. Since it's more explicit about the fact that the parameter is a simple pointer, perhaps that will work better.

Comment: I've tried the first option the compiler gives the following message: AxSomeCompLib::AxSomeComp::CopyToBuffer' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'cli::pin_ptr<Type>' to 'short %. for the second option, I'll try. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know how to change the method signature to `CopyToBuffer(IntPtr ptr)`. The ilasm.exe gives a syntax error at token 'IntPtr'.